# Meteor loads a lot of scripts on the client side, more than 100.

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

The problem is, that every time I start meteor project, it loads ton of dependencies. I've tried to search, and the only thing I found is this question:

[same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411938/meteorjs-how-to-control-the-program-json-file)

Still no answer. I've tried to create new app, reinstall meteor, and it also happens. Doing this on windows 10.

Comment: What's your question? Is it just the same as the one you linked to?

Comment: It's the same with exception that i've tried to install totally new meteor and totally new project, and this still happens, and I can't find any word about this in meteor documentation, also there is no possible way to ask this question to meteor support, so what should I do?

Comment: Sigh, they're trying to [direct their tech support questions to stack overflow](https://www.meteor.com/contact)... and there are [almost 4K meteor tagged questions with no answers](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/meteor?tab=noanswers). they do mention a few other forums on their contact page at least - suggest [file an issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues) with them directly

Comment: Thanks, I just thought that somebody could give some ideas, cause other people who use meteor, that I spoke to, haven't got this problems. Sorry if this question break any stackoverflow rules.

Comment: Meteor is a complete application framework, and you will not get all of the rich feature set for free. It is normal. Even with non-meteor projects, if you look in the node_modules folder you will see hundreds of packages loaded, even though you perhaps only explicitly asked for 10 or 20. I think don't worry about it is your best solution, or look at the package visualiser to see if you can reduce what's loaded at first page load time.

Comment: I've found out, that  this can be a problem with meteor being deployed not in production mode, because when I started meteor locally in production mode the scripts stopped appearing. The problems still stays here. I've deployed meteor in production mode, and checked that it is so, but scripts are still loaded, here is screenshot https://i.imgur.com/kJhwmEo.png to understand the level of despair

Comment: This should be re-asked as a question about deploying Meteor in production mode. When you do that *correctly* Meteor will *bundle* all the js into a single file and all the css into a second file. In the debugger you'll see `index.html`, a js file, a css file and some font references and that's it. If you're seeing hundreds of js files then you're not in production mode and all the individual packages and your own app's js files are all there individually and not minified so that you can debug.

Comment: @StupidUser as explained by Michel Floyd, a Meteor app correctly built for production should automatically bundle all your JS into a single file. If that is not your situation, you should describe how you deploy for production if you need help.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think that loosing all the rating on stackoverflow when asking one small question, just demotivates me using stackoverflow. Your time worth more than my useless personality.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. There are 2 ways of deploying meteor.  First is using their own hosting and deploying instrument Galaxy. And second is using other services and 'meteor-up' instrument created and maintained not by meteor devs. So as I understand most of problems goes from incorrect config file of meteor-up package. I maybe mistaken, but in new version of this package, when you init meteor up config file, it puts

buildOptions: {
        debug: true,
},

which creates all  hundreds of dependencies on the client side. Now you can downvote me to zero. Thanks.

Comment: Nice to come back and share your findings! :-) Just for the record, there are more ways of deploying a Meteor app. You do not necessarily need meteorup if you do not use Galaxy. For example, with Heroku and the appropriate Meteor buildpack, you can deploy directly from your source code, and your app will be built for production on Heroku's side. (I am _not_ part of Heroku)